# Turning arrays into objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is converting an array to object possible? If yes, how would I do the following;

```
[
  ["Awesome Box", "awesome_box"],
  ["Exclusive Box", "exclusive_box"]
]
```

into

```
{
  awesome_box: "Awesome Box",
  exclusive_box: "Exclusive Box"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Object.fromEntries for that

```js
const data = [
  ["Awesome Box", "awesome_box"],
  ["Exclusive Box", "exclusive_box"]
]

const obj = Object.fromEntries(data.map(([v, k]) => [k, v]))

console.log(obj)
```

I now notice that you want to usa the second argument as key so you have to map it